# Find or produce data streams for simulations in RESTful API Web Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, web-services

at the time of this post, I am creating the roadmap for my MSc thesis based on RESTful API Web Services by using Java Spring Boot. The scope of my thesis goes around IoT devices and the data being produced by them and then making simulations to extract results, back to the clients.

In order to do so, I need to find a way in producing data in the input of my service for the aforementioned simulations to take place.

Can anyone give me a suggestion about approaching this issue? Should I create a separate app for the data stream creation?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a synch service with a cronjob or something.

```html
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@Service
public class SynchService {

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * ?")
private void synchSomething() throws IOException {
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check it.